# Git-missing some files

Tags: git

When I'm trying to push my local repository to an empty remote repository, I am doing the following:

```
git add .
git status
```

When im running `git status`, I see that some files are not staged, here is a screenshot of my git bash and my local working copy:

[image: Screeshot of git bash and my local working copy.]

My ignore file:

```
*.*

#####Directories
!CefSharp/Internals/*
!CefSharp/Properties/*

!CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess/Properties/*

!CefSharp.Core/Internals/*
!CefSharp.Core/Win32/*

!CefSharp.Example/ExtensionMethods/*
!CefSharp.Example/Properties
!CefSharp.Example/Proxy
!CefSharp.Example/Resources

!CefSharp.WinForms/Internals/*
!CefSharp.WinForms/Properties/*

!CefSharp.WinForms.Example/Minimal/*
!CefSharp.WinForms.Example/Properties/*
!CefSharp.WinForms.Example/Resources/*
!CefSharp.WinForms.Example/Tools/*

!ipch/*
!packages/*
!Resources/*
!RexCao/Properties/*

!SysHandle/Properties/*

!TimesheetUpdater/Properties/*
!TimesheetUpdater/Resources/*
!TimesheetUpdater/Tools/*

!TSNetChecker/Properties/*
!TSNetChecker/Resource/*
!TSNetChecker/Resources/*
!TSNetChecker/Tools/*

!UIThreadTest/Properties/*

!Win32/*

#####Files
!CefSharp/*.cs
!CefSharp/*.csproj

!CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess/app*
!CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess/*.csproj
!CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess/*.cs

!CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core/*.cpp
!CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core/*.h
!CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core/*.vcxproj.*
!CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core/*.config

!CefSharp.Core/*.cpp
!CefSharp.Core/*.h
!CefSharp.Core/*.vcxproj.*
!CefSharp.Core/*.config

!CefSharp.Example/*.cs
!CefSharp.Example/*.csproj

!CefSharp.WinForms/*.csproj
!CefSharp.WinForms/*.cs

!CefSharp.WinForms.Example/*.cs
!CefSharp.WinForms.Example/app.*
!CefSharp.WinForms.Example/*.csproj.*
!CefSharp.WinForms.Example/*.ico
!CefSharp.WinForms.Example/*.config
!CefSharp.WinForms.Example/*.resx

!RexCao/*.cs
!RexCao/*.csproj

!SysHandle/*.cs
!SysHandle/*.csproj

!TimesheetUpdater/*.ico
!TimesheetUpdater/*.cs
!TimesheetUpdater/*.resx
!TimesheetUpdater/*.csproj

!TSNetChecker/*.cs
!TSNetChecker/*.resx
!TSNetChecker/*.ico
!TSNetChecker/*.csproj

!UIThreadTest/*.config
!UIThreadTest/*.cs
!UIThreadTest/*.resx
!UIThreadTest/*.csproj

!.gitignore
!*.ps1
!*.yml
!*.bat
!*.props
!*.snk
!*.sdf
!*.sln
```

My question is: Why some files were missed?

Comment: What I mean is the files under packages folder were missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to include *all* files under a directory, you must specify it as:

```
!directory/**
```

not with a single asterisk (`*`).

Since you have specified to ignore all files

```
*.*
```

except the ones you include with a bang (`!`), you must specify correctly the files you want to add.

## Background

As you can read in the [specifications](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) a single asterisk matches the files *directly* under the directory. Not files in the subdirectories.

In order to *un-ignore* all files in the directory, you need to use two consecutive asterisks:

> Two consecutive asterisks ("`**`") in patterns matched against full
>   pathname may have special meaning:
>
> - A leading "`**`" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, "`**/foo`" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, the
>     same as pattern "`foo`". "`**/foo/bar`" matches file or directory "`bar`"
>     anywhere that is directly under directory "`foo`".
> - A trailing "`/**`" matches everything inside. For example, "`abc/**`" matches all files inside directory "`abc`", relative to the location of
>     the `.gitignore` file, with infinite depth.
> - A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash matches zero or more directories. For example, "`a/**/b`" matches "`a/b`",
>     "`a/x/b`", "`a/x/y/b`" and so on.
>
> Other consecutive asterisks are considered invalid.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I want. :) @CommuSoft

Answer (score 1):

Git add does not include chucks from files that are in the index.

Please use

```
git add . --all
```

to include all files and remove the deleted ones.

Comment: The `--all` flag is an alias for `--no-ignore-removal`, so this will ony remove files, while files are apparently missing. The `--all` flag will thus only remove more files.

Comment: --add, -A --no-ignore-removal: Update the index not only where the working tree has a file matching <pathspec> but also where the index already has an entry. This adds, modifies, and removes index entries to match the working tree. source: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add

Comment: @CommuSoft: I edited my answer, because I made a mistake: git add consideres only the files which are not included in the index.

Comment: @CommuSoft: This was my third answer in S O ever, so who am I to blame you, a person with 17 k reputation. My last comment should only inform you that I've edited my answer. Even if you give me a -1 (is that the meaning of dv?), i'll accept that and try to improve my next answer.

Comment: dv indeed means -1, since I think you dont deserve a dv will do +1. Reputation is not really a good way to measure quality I think. In many cases reputation is merely an inheritance of enough answers that are old enough.

Answer (score 0):

**Are you trying to add empty directories?**
Git will not let you unless you set content to those folders? Add an empty `.gitkeep` file to the folder and it will be added

**Ignored files**
Have you checked that the ignored files are not set in the global ignore file

**Are you trying to add removed/renamed files?**
`git add -A` (replacement for `git add.; git add -u .`)