# How to add specific files in git by their number in git status?

Tags: git, git-add

I often encounter the following scenario:

```
modified:   assembly/main.debug.s
modified:   ../src/cd/Config.java
modified:   ../src/cd/memoization/cfg/SubgraphFinder.java
modified:   ../src/cd/memoization/cfg/SubgraphMap.java
modified:   ../src/cd/profiler/Profile.java
modified:   ../test/cd/test/TestSamplePrograms.java
modified:   ../../notes/20150521.txt
```

Here I have a bunch of files and I want to include them in different commits. What I do so far is to do a bunch of `git add <pathspec>` followed by a respective `git commit`. The `<pathspec>` is what annoys me. Is there something like the following?

```
1 modified:   assembly/main.debug.s
2 modified:   ../src/cd/Config.java
3 modified:   ../src/cd/memoization/cfg/SubgraphFinder.java
4 modified:   ../src/cd/memoization/cfg/SubgraphMap.java
5 modified:   ../src/cd/profiler/Profile.java
6 modified:   ../test/cd/test/TestSamplePrograms.java
7 modified:   ../../notes/20150521.txt
```

`git magic 2,3,5 -m "My super simple commit"`

Comment: "I have a bunch of files and I want to include them in different commits".  ok so what are you actually trying to do that requires that?  All files are included in any git repo.  If you change a file the change exists on a branch somewhere, even if just master.  What are you trying to achieve (big picture) that is leading you to this question?

Comment: So, you want something like `git commit -a -m "...."`, but it should be selective (not all modified files as it is done with `-a`)? That would indeed sound like an interesting feature to save some time

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for an interface for git, something like Magit, perhaps? https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/introduction-magit-emacs-mode-git

Comment: I would create a .gitignore file to either excluding all paths you don't want to add or exclude all files and specify the once to be included. Then use `git add . --all` followed by git commit.  Here is a link that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30322696/git-missing-some-files/30322823#30322823

Comment: @MichaelDurrant The big picture is very simple. Just imagine you modify multiple files in a git repo and the changes you made semantically belong in different commits. #Slizzered This is exactly what I want to do. Ideally not by specifying paths individually but by a git status showing some kind of enumeration as in my question to allow easier selection of files. #Peter Paul Kiefer This sounds tedious to me.

Comment: Ah, sorry I've overseen your requirement of adding files in different commits. I think then you have to specify the paths in git add separated by spces and with wildcard notation if you want to add all files in a directory `git add dir/**`

Comment: Have you considered using a git client? Like [tig](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/git-tig/)

Comment: @bdecaf If you are talking about GUI clients then yes. I'm looking for something without GUI.

Comment: @ben - just for clarification - even tig wich runs in the console?

Comment: @bdecaf I took a look at tig. Something like that also looks fine. I just want something running in the console.

Comment: @ben I've found one more tool, SCM Breeze. This one seems to be more powerful. Have a look )

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Commits should strive to be atomic rather than contain a huge mass of unrelated changes. Organising modified files into separate commits is a fairly common workflow.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Example repo:

I'm using an example repo with four files: a, b, c, d.
Here `a` is tracked, changed and staged; `b` is tracked, changed and not staged; `c` in untracked and staged; `d` is just untracked.

[image]

## External tool: [git-number](https://github.com/holygeek/git-number)

> When run without arguments, 'git number' runs 'git status' and attach a unique number for each line of filename printed by 'git status', and it will 'remember' this number-to-filename association. When run with arguments, like this:

```
$ git number <any git command> [one or more numbers or git options/args]
```

> 'git number' will run that  and subtitute all the numbers to their equivalent filenames. Non-numeric argument are passed intact to git.

[image]

This is available with other commands.

[image]

## External tool: [SCM Breeze](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/scm_breeze)

> SCM Breeze is a set of shell scripts (for bash and zsh) that enhance your interaction with git. It integrates with your shell to give you numbered file shortcuts, a repository index with tab completion, and many other useful features.

SCM Breeze utilizes keyboard shortcuts and aliases to work with git files by number:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd> => `git_add_and_commit` - add given files (if any), then commit staged changes

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> => `git_commit_all` - commit everything

`git add`:

```
$ ga 1
```

`git diff`:

```
$ gd 2
```

`git reset`:

```
$ grs 3
```

`git commit`:

```
$ gco 4
```

## Native way with `git add -i`

```
git add -i
```

From [Git reference](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-add):

> **-i**
>   **--interactive**
>   Add modified contents in the working tree interactively to the index. Optional path arguments may be supplied to limit operation to a subset of the working tree. See “Interactive mode” for details.

You can remember this as `-i`ntuitive, because the interface is really intuitive. Well, at least to hardcore Vim users.

Opening the interactive mode:
[image]

Adding (staging) a tracked file:
[image]

Adding an untracked file:
[image]

See the changes:
[image]

If you're stuck in the middle of adding, hit <kbd>Return</kbd> with an empty string.

**Note:**

If you're confused with the appearance and coloring: I've been using [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/) + [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) + [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).

Comment: As far as i know git -i only allows to add untracked paths to the stage. Does this also allow to add updated files? If not, how would I exclude them from the commit?

Comment: I've added a tool that does just exactly what you want.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer: `git add -i` does everything that `git add` can. So, it can add updated files, and remove them.

Comment: @NickVolynkin yep, I think the number tool is the solution. I didnt know of that before. Thank you.

Comment: Btw, git-number is available in Homebrew, if you're on Mac.

Comment: @JeanHominal git add only allows to remove files with the --all switch. No chance to select files. But you point me to a problem. You are right, if git add does not allow me to remove files from the stage. How can a avoid commiting them? That is a problem if I intend to add already staged files in seperate commits. git rm --cached could do the job. I think GUIs do it this way.  The number tool mentioned by Nick Volynkin could handle this too.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer use `git reset <filename>` to unstage files.

Comment: @NickVolynkin  Of cause git reset in its simple form is the inverse of git add. I was so stupid. Perhaps because the last time, I often used git reset --hard to throw away some tryouts.

Comment: My main peeve with interactive add is that it's clunky. There's a lot of boilerplate steps simply to add files by index

Comment: @void.pointer: interactive add is definitely not the best way.